# isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() returns ConnectionResult.SUCCESS when service is missing

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have implemented the code that checks whether the play services are available as usual:

```
mGooglePlayServicesAvailable = false;
GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    mGooglePlayServicesAvailable = true;
}
else if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
    apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, RC_AVAILABILITY).show();
}
```

My problem is that resultCode seems to be ConnectionResult.SUCCESS even if the services are missing. This crashes my android app on many devices.

P.S. I can see the following line in logcat, which is rather weird.

```
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12419): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this behavior or, if there is a better way to check if the play services are available?

Many thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that the reason behind ConnectionResult.SUCCESS is that 'Google Play Services' are indeed available and up to date. The app that was disabled was 'Google Play Games', so I just had to extend my code a bit to better handle this situation:

```
mGooglePlayGamesAvailable = false;
try {
    int status = getPackageManager().getApplicationEnabledSetting("com.google.android.play.games");
    switch(status) {
        case PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT:
        case PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED:
            // check if play services are up to date
            GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
            int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                mGooglePlayGamesAvailable = true;
            }
            else if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, RC_AVAILABILITY).show();
            }
            break;
    }

} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {}
```

I hope this helps someone, many thanks for your attention and happy coding.

P.S. Please do comment if you think this solution is not elegant enough.